# Disabling ArcGIS Server web adf calls when zooming with a mouse wheel?

Tags: arcgis-server, zoom, arcgis-web-adf, mouse-wheel

When zooming using the mouse wheel on a web adf based map, every time the map wheel clicks, requests are sent to ArcGIS Server for maps etc. (as evident in Fiddler).

Is there any way to harvest an event that would disable the requests until you got to zoom level you want?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a few options:

1. Disable the built-in ADF scroll wheel handler (see ScrollWheelZoom in the [ADF Documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0002000000m0000000)) and then use the ADF Javascript library to handle the zooming.
2. Add an event to your Map control's ScaleChanged event that enabled or disabled the ScrollWheelZoom at run-time.
3. Place a `<div>` over your map control that intercepts mouse movement and relays them to the map control (except when out of scale range).